additionalProperties: false does not work in OpenAPI3.0.2
I am using OpenAPI:3.0.2
My openAPI properties are as follows:
    abc:
      type: object
      additionalProperties: false
      required:
        - something
        - id
      properties:
        something:
          $ref: '#/xyz'
        id:
          description: id.
          type: string
          minLength: 1
          maxLength: 100


When my request body is like this:
"abc": [
            {
                "something": "dfg",
                "id": "45345342",
                "ccc": "ugfyc"
            },
            {
                "something": "iut",
                "id": "45345342"
            }

        ]

It does not raise any error or invalidate the schema even if additional properties is sent
I tried changing it's level and also adding unevaluatedProperties it still doesn't work
Tried using unevaluatedProperties: false, still did not work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Your OpenAPI schema and the data instance are different, that's why the validation doesn't work as expected.
You have abc as type: object in your schema
    abc:
      type: object
      additionalProperties: false
      required:
        - something
        - id
      properties:
        something:
          $ref: '#/xyz'
        id:
          description: id.
          type: string
          minLength: 1
          maxLength: 100

and your data instance has abc as type: array. So the validation is never executed because your abc data instance doesn't match the expected type.
The schema can be adjusted to the following:
  abc:
    type: array
    items:
      type: object
      additionalProperties: false
      properties:
        id:
          description: id
          type: string
          minLength: 1
          maxLength: 100
        ccc:
           type: string
        something:
          $ref: '#/xyz'

